# What role does public-key cryptography play in bitcoin transaction?

Tags: blockchain, public-key, cryptography

Explain in one word and kindly tell what is it exactly that public-key cryptography does in bitcoin.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice (public-key cryptography is a synonym for asymmetric cryptography).

Comment: It is a different question, please answer it if possible. I am 17 yr old need it to work on my extended essay

Comment: I've already answered it in your other question.

Comment: Can you share your email id, it would be really helpful if you check my research and verify if it is correct or not.